# Regular Expression to check if string ends with one underscore and two letters with php

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to check if a string ends with one `_` and two letters on an old system with php. I've check here on stackoverflow for answers and I found one that wanted to do the same but with one `.` and two digits.

I tried to change it to work with my needs, and I got this:

`\\.*\\_\\a{2,2}$`

Then I went to php and tried this:

`$regex = '(\\.*\\_\\a{2,2}$)';
echo preg_match($regex, $key);`

But this always returns an error, saying the following:

`preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

I get this happens because I can't use the backslashes or something, how can I do this correctly? And also, is my regex correct(I don't know ho to form this expressions and how they work)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with delimiters:

```
$regex = '/_[a-z]{2}$/i';
```

You're getting that error because in PHP every regex needs a delimiter (not use of `/` above which can be any other character like `~` also).

Comment: what if I had to test it too, if the string is ends with: `_**_slug`
beeing the `*` random letters and `_slug` a specific word? would I do this:

`'/_[a-z]{2}_slug$/i'`

Comment: Then it would be: `$regex = '/_([a-z]{2}|.*?_slug)$/i';`

Answer (score 1):

```
^.*_[a-zA-Z]{2}$
```

This should do it for you.

```
    $re = "/^.*_[a-zA-Z]{2}$/"; 
    $str = "abc_ac"; 

    preg_match($re, $str);
```